# Yocto throws a git Fatal Error "Please tell me who you are" after after successful Bitbake build

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

After every successful recipe / image build using Bitbake in Yocto, GIT throws out a Fatal Error "Please tell me who you are" (I have attached the detailed output below)

As far as my understanding, this part has only to do with git not being able to commit since it has not been configured and has nothing to do with do_fetch. Am I right?

But i don't wish to use git for my Yocto Projects, therefore don't intend to configure it (neither global nor local), as I am already using SVN.

The part that I don't understand is why does Bitbake (Yocto) throw out this error? How do I get rid of it?

Note: all info such as poky version, host system, architecture is included in the build config.

```
WARNING: Buildfile specified, dependencies will not be handled. If this is not what you want, do not use -b / --buildfile.

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "CentOS-Linux-7.1.1503"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "arm-cortex-a8"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.8"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp neon callconvention-hard cortexa8"
TARGET_FPU        = "vfp-neon"
meta-python       
meta-networking   
meta-python       
meta-networking   
meta-python       
meta-networking   
..*shortened*..
meta-python       
meta-networking   
meta-python       
meta-networking   = "master:54def94d4e7aa8900fec58e6aaef8f8c3b0b563e"
meta-xxxxxbsp-ti     
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    
meta-xxxxx-common   = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta-oe           = "master:54def94d4e7aa8900fec58e6aaef8f8c3b0b563e"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Running setscene task 2 of 6 (/opt/xxxxx/yocto/trunk/yocto/meta- 
xxxxx/meta-xxxxx-common/recipes-xxxxxx/chrony/chrony_3.1.bb, 
do_populate_sysroot_setscene)
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_populate_sysroot_setscene: Started
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_populate_sysroot_setscene: Succeeded
NOTE: Running setscene task 3 of 6 (/opt/xxxxx/yocto/trunk/yocto/meta- 
xxxxx/meta-xxxxx-common/recipes-xxxx/chrony/chrony_3.1.bb, 
do_package_qa_setscene)
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_package_qa_setscene: Started
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_package_qa_setscene: Succeeded
NOTE: Running setscene task 4 of 6 (/opt/xxxxx/yocto/trunk/yocto/meta- 
xxxxx/meta-xxxxx-common/recipes-xxxxx/chrony/chrony_3.1.bb, 
do_package_write_rpm_setscene)
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_package_write_rpm_setscene: Started
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_package_write_rpm_setscene: Succeeded
NOTE: Running setscene task 5 of 6 (/opt/xxxxx/yocto/trunk/yocto/meta- 
xxxxx/meta-xxxxx-common/recipes-xxxxx/chrony/chrony_3.1.bb, 
do_packagedata_setscene)
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_packagedata_setscene: Started
NOTE: recipe chrony-3.1-r0: task do_packagedata_setscene: Succeeded
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Running noexec task 13 of 13 (ID: 10, 
/opt/xxxxx/yocto/trunk/yocto/meta-xxxxx/meta-xxxxx-common/recipes- 
xxxxx/chrony/chrony_3.1.bb, do_build)
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 13 tasks of which 12 didn't need to be rerun 
and all succeeded.

Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <xxxxx@localhost.localdomain>) not allowed

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <xxxxx@localhost.localdomain>) not allowed
```

Any input on how to get rid of this error or could shed some more light on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "buildhistory" feature uses git commits to store the history. git requires a name and email when commiting (because usually the commits are later published).

You can fix the problem by doing what the warning suggests. Run in terminal:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Alternatively disable the buildhistory feature in your configuration.

> But i don't wish to use git for my Yocto Projects

This isn't really an option: All of the common Yocto layers are stored in git and fetch things from various git repos. Git is practically a requirement and is already working on your system if you got this far -- it's just that fetching does not require an email address and a name.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 
Yes. I acknowledge that all yocto layers are stored in the git repos. I do use them.
Sorry, by that I meant. I don't wish to use git for the commit part, not for the fetch.

So, my only option would be to disable buildhistory.

Thank you very much @jku.